# CKEditor error in internet explorer version8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor version 4.2 full version.For uploading image in ckeditor i have used the following code on document ready:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {                
       filebrowserUploadUrl: '/SendNewsletter/UploadImage'(This is Controller)
 });
 <html>
 <textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor1" cols="10" rows="10"></textarea><br />
        <input type="button" value="Send Bulk Msg" id="Compose" />
 </html>
```

It is absolutely fine in firefox and chrome.But in IE8 i'm getting the following error:
"The editor instance "'+b.getEditor().name+'" is already attached to the provided element"

when i pass the exception on the program being debugged,then upload button is invisible in the editor.and also the submit buton is not working.

Comment: Line: 632
Error: Unable to get value of the property 'items': object is null or undefined I am gettiing above error in IE8 ,while CKEDITOR.replace(email_promoMsg,{ width:"445px" });
code excution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox and Chrome should give you exactly the same error, but as they don't show javascript errors so obviously you're not aware of it.

Your textarea has a class of "ckeditor", so it's automatically used by CKEditor and then it throws you the error because it's already been replaced.

Remove that class and your problem will be gone.